# Evaluate any type or function using templates

Tags: c++, templates, boost

I LEFT ALL THE PREVIOUS WRITING FOR DOCUMENTARY ISSUES, IN THE MEANTIME LOADS OF THINGS GOT CLEARED UP, EDIT2 IS THE CURRENT STATE:

I am currently working on a simple GUI system for my university coursework and I came up with a simple idea and question. I was thinking about a kind of dynamic label:

Instead of passing a value/string every frame to a "static" label, I thought it would be nice if a "dynamic" label class could simply bind every kind of function or pointer to print them automatically every frame.

Here's some pseudo-code to demonstrate, what I want to achieve:

```
/* OLD WAY */
// called on initialization:
CView* pView = new CView();
CLabel* pLabel = new CLabel(10,20,"TEST");
pView->Attach(pLabel);
GUIManager->SetActive(pView);
// ...
// called every frame somewhere:
pLabel->SetText(AppTime->GetFPS()); //(AppTime is a singelton with time informations)

/* NEW WAY */
// called on initialization:
CView* pView = new CView();
//(the return type of GetFPS is float)
CDynamicLabel<float>* pDLabel = new DynamicLabel<float>(10,20, *AppTime->GetFPS());
// not only functions or member functions, this should also be possible
CDynamicLabel<int>* pDLabel2 = new DynamicLabel<int>(20,20, ptrToSomeInteger);
```

So I think there must be a way to combine the C++ templating system and boost::bind to get this functionality I want, but I can't figure out how. 
I hope someone can give me some hints on how to achieve this. Maybe there is even another way to get this functionality that is more common.

EDIT:
To clear some things up, the C++ code related to the Dynamic Label is not yet implemented. I am still struggling to find the perfect way to implement it, but to clear some things up about my current class hierarchy:

I have a virtual class CElement, which every GUIElement gets derived from. There are virtual functions for rendering, updating(with the passed time as argument) and an OnEvent function with the event as argument. Also general visibility function are implemented in the CElement class. 
The CView is a class that represents a certain setup of CElements.
The GUIManager is a Singleton that forwards all calls to the current view and associated elements.

My basic idea was because the GUI system is part of a game, that the update function gets called anyway every frame if there would be a generic way to achieve self updating labels instead of writing another derived class for a certain label that should simply print the fps to the screen or similar.

I hope that cleared things somehow up...

EDIT2:
/* deleted because code wasnt working anyway... */

EDIT3:
Got everything working, I used boost::function and boost::bind and wrote a template that can now can do everything I wanted...

Comment: Is `CDynamicLabel<T>` derived from `CLabel` for all `T`?

Comment: You could do this, but there would still be the issue of when those functions get called.  How do the labels know when the frame changes?

Comment: If `getFPS` returns `float` then `*appTime->GetFPS()` doesn't make too much sense. I think you meant something of the kind `bind(&Time::GetFPS, &AppTime)`

Comment: I called it pseudo-code because it is not yet implemented but I wanted to represent my thoughts using C++ like syntax, because part of the code is actually implemented (but the CDynamicLabel-class does not yet exist). Edited original post with some extra informations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone who wants to do something similar here is my final simple testcode I came up with, which illustrates the functionality:

```
/* DynamicLabel.hpp */
template <class T> class CDynamicLabel : public CElement
{    
public:
    CDynamicLabel(void) {}
    CDynamicLabel(boost::function0<T> f) : m_f(f) {}
    void TestCall(void) const { cout << m_f(); }
private:
    boost::function0<T> m_f;
};
/* Test Code in Main (MEMFUNC is a Macro to simplify binding and AppTime is a definition to simplify the CAppTime-Singleton calls) */
CDynamicLabel<float> TestDL(MEMFUNC(&CAppTime::GetLastGPUDelta, AppTime));
TestDL.TestCall();
```

Answer (score 1):

Would you give a bit more details of the use-case?

AFAICT, in the example you've provided, the value is going to have to be converted to text somewhere, so that the value can be rendered onto the screen. Yes?

So I can understand handing a pointer or reference to text which will be rendered into the label. Then the 'user-side' program can change the text after the label has been created. But that does leave undefined how the label knows it must re-render the text. So this isn't ideal.

I can also understand passing a function pointer to the label. The function would return (a pointer to) the piece of text which is to be rendered.  This is useful because that function  executes to work out if the value has changed, and convert the value to text accordingly.

Again it is undefined how the label knows that it needs to call the function. But assuming that the attempted label can work this out, it is exactly the same problem, so I assume that is solved.

This seems to be the only essential case. Everything else seems to be doable using it. So the label could be templated on the function, which hides the type, rather than the data type of the value, which is irrelevant because it must be converted to text anyway.

The further advantage of this is the function can ensure the format looks correct. I like things like frame time to render as a fixed width field, and ugly if it shrinks and widens.

The generalisation of this is a template class which has type specific accessors for the 'user-side' program to set and update the value, and a fixed function which returns the string to be rendered.

Summary: template on a function which returns a text string, or template on a class which has a well-defined function which returns a text string.

Edit (as a result of pizza)
This might be a helpful way to think about it.

An elegant solution to sme problems is 'interfaces' (like Java, or Golang, or ...).

In this case the interface only needs a single parameter-less function which returns (in my example) a text string. It is the interface which is handed to the label.

The interface needs to embed a value, reference or pointer to the object (class instance or POD) which implements the value, and that class or POD needs to have a way to give a text string.

The class or POD which implements the value is hidden from the label by the interface.

Comment: To not have to be limited to text returning functions I was planning to work with stringstreams in the final class. Anyway I edited the original post again and the problem shifted a bit. Thanks for the thoughts, they cleared some things up!

Comment: @niktehpui - you could +1 me if it helped !-) I have no problem with smarter ways to communicate the text, but something dumb, like a fixed size, static char array, might be easier to get working intitially. My worry with smarter classes is garbage collection and leakage.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know your class hierarchy, but here's a generic idea:

```
#include <type_traits>

struct CLabel { virtual ~CLabel() { } /* ... */ };

template <typename T>
struct DynamicLabel : CLabel
{
    DynamicLabel(T);
    // ...
};

template <typename T>
CLabel * LabelMaker(T x)
{
    return new DynamicLabel<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>(x);
}
```

Now you can use:

```
CLabel * p = LabelMaker(12U), * q = LabelMaker(1.5L);
```

Comment: A nice approach I will keep in mind, but I want to achieve Labels that can update themselfs with data provided by functions and able to update themself every frame. I update the original post to clear things up.